# passing a dataframe as a argument while applying a lambda function on a dataframe

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I am applying a lambda function on a data frame and would like to add a new column to that dataframe, while applying the lambda function I am passing the data frame it self as a argument to the function. 
My code

```
def categorical_fare_mean(data,col,cat):
    print('entered once')
    data = data[data[col]==cat]['Fare']
    fare_mean = data['Fare'].mean()
    return fare_mean

dataset['weekday_encoded'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: categorical_fare_mean(dataset,x['weekday'],0) ,axis = 1)
```

This is giving me an error `KeyError: (0, 'occurred at index 0')` I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can some one help me with it.

Thanks

Comment: What does your data look like? Print your dataframe and column headers. Probably a column mismatch.

Comment: Hi, I have also tried with different column also , i get a  similar error `KeyError: (1, 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is your column ```x["weekday"]```. Try to use `loc` instead of ```data[data[col]==cat]['Fare']```. Moreover you are trying to copy the dataset in the lambda function which is not necessary. So you should rewrite the function and use this to call it: ```dataset['weekday_encoded'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: categorical_fare_mean(x["weekday"],0) ,axis = 1)```

Comment: I think this is poor way of applying function in pandas, maybe explain a bit what you want to do?

Comment: I believe you are looking to take the mean of fare in the function, but I am not sure if you really need to go via lambda to apply this. Please explain the end outcome you are trying to achieve.